# Classes based on BaseSettings completely ignore explicit environment file declarations if a .env exists (?)

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong, but I cannot figure it out:

I'm setting up a project with `FastAPI`, and wanted to do the testing with `pytest`. I set the project so that the environment is read through a `Settings` pydantic class. If it matters, I'm also using `pipenv` to manage my environment.

Now, the project works well if I run it normally, as it takes all of the environment variables from the `.env` file.

For the tests, I decided to override the settings dependency with a version that reads from another environment file, from now on called `test.env`. However, it seems as if the `Settings` object completely ignores that I'm telling it to read from `test.env`, and loads instead what's on the regular `.env` file.

I am 100% sure the override *is* happening: if I manually change every single variable (i.e. by doing `settings.var = 'NEWVALUE'` on each value I want to change), the app recognizes the change on the tests. It's that first load that is not doing what I want, which is to load the values from `test.env`.

My current `conftest.py` looks like this:

```py
from config import Settings, get_settings
from main import app
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from pytest import fixture


def get_test_settings() -> Settings:
    return Settings(_env_file='test.env')


@fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def test_client():
    app.dependency_overrides[get_settings] = get_test_settings
    return TestClient(app)
```

And my `settings.py` file looks like this:

```py
from pydantic import BaseSettings, MongoDsn
from functools import lru_cache


class Settings(BaseSettings):
    version: str
    db_connection_string: MongoDsn
    db_name: str


@lru_cache()
def get_settings() -> Settings:
    return Settings()
```

I have done several iterations of the solution, just to end up in the same place. So far, what I've tried includes:

- Including the `get_test_settings` function into the `settings.py` file.
- Further extending `Settings` into a brand new class.
- Calling the constructor as such: `Settings(_env_file='test.env')`
- Removing the `lru_cache` decorator from everything.
- Doing some shenanigans as to override the dependency outside the fixture.

Also, just to be clear:

- Both `.env` and `test.env` exist on the project's root. They also both contain the exact same variables: they only differ on the actual value.
- `conftest.py` exists on the project's root, but `settings.py` does not: it exists on a submodule called `config`.

I'm currently at a standstill: I really don't want to end up having to manually change all environment variables for the tests, both because the project may grow and need more variables, and because other people might need to change them for their environment and it would end up in a conflict war on the repos. As I mentioned, I'm sure there's something that I'm doing wrong and that I'm missing, but, what could it be?

Answer (score 0):

`pipenv` reads `.env` [automatically](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/#pipenv-features) and sets the environment variables. Since, for Pydantic, [environment variables will always take priority over values loaded from a dotenv file](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/settings/#dotenv-env-support), you see the settings applied from `.env` file.